# how to change or remove background color of google line chart(default is white)?

Tags: google-visualization

**i am drawing line chart with google line chart and using url like below**

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=280x300&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|Jan|Feb|March|April|May|June|July|1:|0|20|40|60|80|100&chd=t:20,50,70,90,45,50,80&chg=18,20&chm=o,FF9900,0,-1,10.0;
```

and the above url given line chart with white background but **i want transparent(no color) or change default color.**

please figure out this one...

Answer (score 0):

Specify the background color with a parameter like: `chf=bg,s,676767`

Full URL example:
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=bg,s,676767&cht=lc&chs=280x300&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|Jan|Feb|March|April|May|June|July|1:|0|20|40|60|80|100&chd=t:20,50,70,90,45,50,80&chg=18,20&chm=o,FF9900,0,-1,10.0;

Use the editor tab in [this Chart Wizard](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Dheeraj V.S. works great!

For transparent background you can use 00000000 instead of 676767